# Wrong use of typedef of typedef(?)

Tags: c++

I have problem with code from book:

```
const int SQUARE_ARRAY_SIZE = 4;
const int SQUARE_INFO_SIZE = 4;
typedef Square SquareArray[SQUARE_ARRAY_SIZE];
typedef SquareArray SquareInfo[SQUARE_INFO_SIZE];

SquareArray RedGeneric = { Square(0, 0), Square(0, 1),
Square(1, 1), Square(1, 0) };
SquareInfo RedInfo = { &RedGeneric, &RedGeneric,  \\problem here
&RedGeneric, &RedGeneric };
```

It yells:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'SquareArray (*)' to 'Square'
>
> IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "SquareArray *" to "Square"

As I understand SquareInfo stands for array of SquareArray but it seems like vs2013 wants to break it to Squares and as result

```
SquareInfo m_squareInfo; ...
SquareArray* pSquareArray = m_squareInfo[m_iDirection];
```

yells:

> IntelliSense: a value of type "const Square *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "SquareArray *"

Book is from 2008 and I don't know if it worked back then or there is error from beginning. As for q please tell me what's really wrong and how to make it work.

Comment: Throw that book in the bin.

Comment: Are you sure the book wrote `typedef SquareArray SquareInfo[SQUARE_INFO_SIZE];` and not `typedef SquareArray * SquareInfo[SQUARE_INFO_SIZE];`? It seems to mean the latter, in any event.

Comment: What book? Or is it just called "Book"?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But only if it's a proper recycle ♻ bin!

Comment: That's really very dreadful code.

Comment: @n.m. May be there's an errata for the book?

Comment: The book is apparently [Microsoft Visual C++ Windows Applications by Example](https://books.google.com/books?id=QUt8hf-TsvoC&pg=PT251&lpg=PT251&dq=typedef+Square+SquareArray[SQUARE_ARRAY_SIZE]%3B&source=bl&ots=9_m5sc1Bni&sig=22nsZXbk1yo-imPQvkrKj1jK4Dw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fwLZVPqaFM3paLLXgrgC&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=typedef%20Square%20SquareArray[SQUARE_ARRAY_SIZE]%3B&f=false)

Comment: @interjay Then this might explain well, if there wouldn't be any errata for it.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I found some errata [here](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/1198) but this issue isn't there.

Comment: @interjay yep that great book, thanks for errata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that the book meant to write

```
typedef SquareArray* SquareInfo[SQUARE_INFO_SIZE];
//                 ^
```

i.e., `SquareInfo` is an array of pointers to `SquareArray`s, rather than an array of `SquareArray`s. This is consistent with initializations using `&RedGeneric` and `SquareArray* pSquareArray = m_squareInfo[m_iDirection];`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your book has a typo on that line

```
typedef SquareArray SquareInfo[SQUARE_INFO_SIZE];
```

When I make this to be a pointer

```
typedef SquareArray* SquareInfo[SQUARE_INFO_SIZE];
                // ^
```

the code [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/wlzK5Z).